# Why is it that the Mist client can not display the transactions?

Tags: transactions, mist, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

"Latest Transactions" not updating in Mist Wallet after sending Eth from Polo to my wallet. Balance is updating fine but can't see any transactions since 3/31.

Comment: you mean your wallet's eth amount stay the same or are you just missing a tx note?

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR: it's computational too expensive to monitor incoming transactions for accounts on the Ethereum blockchain.

linagee [asked the developer](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/493d8z/mist_accounts_cant_display_incoming_transactions/) of Mist:

> Its because you'd need to traverse the entire blockchain which is very computationally intensive. Ethereum blockchain explorer websites do it, because they are fine with the extra processing load.
>
> This should likely be fixed in a newer version. (When geth / go-ethereum exposes the ability to ask for transactions that included an address in the past and monitor them in the future.)
>
> Right now, Wallet Contracts have a contract Event that they listen for, which is why they can get live upd