# Transaction executed through sendTransaction() not effective and not shown in Mist, private net

Tags: web3js, transactions, mist

I am trying to execute a transaction in my private net using the Java 
 Script console, with sendTransaction(), and the state variables that should change after the execution don't change, in other words it's not effective. When I execute it from Mist, it's effective. Any ideas?
[image: it went to the mining queue]

Comment: Is the miner running? Execute in the geth console `miner.start(1)` to start mining, and `miner.stop()` to stop it.

Comment: Yes, it is. Even though it cannot be seen, the first console of the image is the miner running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it that the Mist client can not display the transactions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2742/why-is-it-that-the-mist-client-can-not-display-the-transactions)

Comment: Actually it's not. I have edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: what are you getting as a result of `eth.getTransaction(txHash)` ?

Comment: If the state didn't change very likey you didn't supply enough gas to the transaction and it failed. Check with `eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash)` if gasUsed is the same amount of gas set in the transaction. Or you can try setting a higher gas when sending the transaction.